# Converting a 50MHz clock to 1Hz to blink an LED

Tags: led, verilog, clock, code, microsemi-fpga

My board uses a 50MHz clock which I am trying to convert to 1Hz so that I can blink an LED.

The way my code works is it counts up to 25,000,000 and then the divided clock signal switches from 0 to 1. Then, the counter starts back at 0 and counts up to 25,000,000 again where the divided clock signal then switches from 1 to 0. I am doing this so that the LED is on for 0.5 seconds and off for 0.5 seconds.

The issue I am having is when my "localparam div_value = 24,999,999;" the divided clock signal is changing every 1 seconds instead of every 0.5 seconds.

I thought this was because I had the clock defined wrong in my testbench but I am using "'timescale 1ns/100ps" and my clock driver is defined as "#10 clk = ~clk" meaning that my period is 20ns.

What am I doing wrong here?

//////////////////////// HDL Code ///////////////////////////

```
module blinking_LED( clk, divided_clk );
    input clk;
    output divided_clk;

    wire clk;
    reg divided_clk = 0;

    localparam div_value = 24999999;

    //<statements>
    // division_value = 50MHz/(2*desired_value) - 1

    integer counter_value = 0;

    // counter 
    always@ (posedge clk)
    begin
        if (counter_value == div_value)
            counter_value <= 0;
        else 
            counter_value <= counter_value+1;
        end 

     // clock divider
     always@ (posedge clk)
     begin
        if(counter_value == div_value)
           divided_clk <= ~divided_clk;    // Suppose to occur after 0.5sec
        else
           divided_clk <= divided_clk;     // If the counter is not at its limit, do nothing 
        end
     endmodule
```

//////////////////// Testbench Code /////////////////////

```
'timescale 1ns/100ps

module blinking_LED_tb;
reg clk ;                   // input
wire divided_clk;           // output 

initial 
begin
   clk = 0;
end

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Clock Driver
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

always 
   #10 clk = ~clk;

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       Instantiate Unit Under Test:  blinking_LED

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 blinking_LED blinking_LED_0 (

// Inputs
.clk(clk),

// Outputs
.divided_clk(divided_clk)

// Inouts

 );

endmodule
```

Comment: I don't know squat about HDL code, but I find it odd that a statement like "counter_value <= 0" would be an assignment instead of part of an "if then" decision tree.  I read it like "counter value less than or equal to zero", not "put zero into counter_value".    Since I don't know HDL, I"m not posing a solution - Just an observation.....

Comment: Another hack - Instead of figuring it out, you could set your timer to trip at 12,499,999.   Presumably that'd give you your 0.5Hz instead of 1Hz

Comment: @KyleB `<=` is an assignment in `verilog` ... http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/simple_counter.html#8-Bit_Simple_Up_Counter

Comment: @yer you are flipping the output every second ... why would you expect the output to change every 1/2 second?

Comment: I only know VHDL, but I can't spot anything obviously wrong. You could try counting to 50,000,000 and <25000000 turn your LED off and >=25000000 turn your LED on and see if that behaves any differently. It isn't possible that your clock is actually 25MHz is it?

Answer (score -1):

The obvious thing: if you want to divide a 50 MHz clock to 1 Hz, you need to divide by 50 million, so you need to count to 50 million, not to 25 million.

The finer points: in a production design you don't want to run a counter off a fast clock to generate a slower clock. It can be done, but you're counting on the compiler to recognize what you are doing. Clocks and resets are high-fanout networks that are distributed using dedicated circuitry, and there is usually no way for a logic output to enter back into the clock network, so using the counter output as a clock will give you synthesis warnings.

There are two ways around that: generating an enable signal that is synchronous to the fast clock, and generating a slower clock with a PLL.

The enable signal is basically a signal that's high for exactly one cycle, you'd feed that back into the counter reset, and use it as an enable on whatever logic you want to drive. This still keeps a strong timing dependency between circuits, but since the signal isn't a clock, the compiler can decide to regenerate it wherever needed by duplicating the logic.

If phase doesn't matter (such as for an LED), then the PLL is the best choice. You will still need to combine it with a counter because the PLL is going to have a minimum frequency, but since you are feeding that counter with a slower clock, the timing relationships are less strict, so the optimizer needs to work less hard for your design to meet timing. If there's nothing else going on, that doesn't matter, but when you add more logic you can see compile times increase drastically otherwise.

For counters, there are also various tricks to improve resource usage and timing closure, depending on the fabric you use -- some fabrics support loads (i.e. reset to `'1'`), some have a carry output from logic elements. For example, on some fabrics it is best to initialize the counter to \$2^{26}-50000000-1 = 17108863\$, and count upwards until it wraps, then use the carry over as the reset signal and output pulse on the next cycle, that way you save the logic required for the comparison.

Also, depending on the compiler you use, it might not matter. If you want to learn a bit about synthesis, look at the generated logic at different stages (RTL, post-mapping, post-fitting) to see how it is translated to actual logic.

Comment: The reason the OP is counting to 25,000,000 is because the OP is toggling twice per second, which results in a 1Hz blinking speed. Instead of counting from 0 to 50,000,000 and changing LED states halfway through, the OP is instead counting from 0 to 25,000,000 and reversing the LED state each time.

Comment: ... and the OP **is** using an enable signal to toggle the output -- that's what the `if (counter_value == div_value) divided_clk <= ~divided_clk;` is all about. He's never using `divided_clk` *as a clock*.